# How to use traditional rounding for decimal numbers in Python (version 3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I'm trying to figure out how to round decimal numbers using the traditional method that is taught in elementary and middle schools using Python version 3 (specifically version 3.4.0).

For example, using the decimal number **0.745**, I am trying to round it to the nearest hundredth.
Traditionally, the rounded value would be 0.75, but the following code gives me 0.74:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> a = decimal.Decimal("0.745")
>>> round(a, 2)
Decimal('0.74')
```

However, changing the original value to **0.746** seems to return 0.75:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> b = decimal.Decimal("0.746")
>>> round(b, 2)
Decimal('0.75')
```

This seems to contradict traditional rounding (if I remember correctly).
Can someone lead me to the correct way of rounding in Python?

**Update:**
Using the guidance from the selected answer, here is the full code solution to my question:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> a = decimal.Decimal("0.745")
>>> round(a, 2)
Decimal('0.75')
```

Comment: There is nothing _unexpected_ in what you observe.

Comment: I believe the author is referring to a rounding heuristic described [here](http://www.math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U1L3GL.html).

Comment: Huu, thanks that link shows exactly what I was referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the expected (and best) behavior: so-called "banker's rounding" which is unbiased and rounds halves to the nearest even whole number.

You can always:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
```

Note that `ROUND_HALF_UP` has bias, which is why it's not default.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich! I had never heard of "banker's rounding" until now.
After doing some more research on it, I agree that it is, generally, better than the traditional rounding method I learned.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what precision to round to, you can always add a bit extra to round it how you want (and not necessarily what others would expect):

```
def round_my_way(dec, precision):
    dec += decimal.Decimal(1.0/10**(precision+1) / 2)
    return round(dec, precision)

print round_my_way(decimal.Decimal("0.746"), 2) # Prints 0.75
print round_my_way(decimal.Decimal("0.745"), 2) # Prints 0.75
print round_my_way(decimal.Decimal("0.744"), 2) # Prints 0.74
```

Comment: Thanks Huu! Although the other answer was more relevant to this question, this is still good to know. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I voted up the other answer because I didn't know that you could change the rounding heuristic like that.